# force warning/error 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I want to put some warning or error into my code. I am using visual studio 2010.

I used `#error` and `#warning` in Xcode, but visual studio doesn't know those directives.

Answer (score 8):

After some searching through different articles, I finally came to this solution which works in Visual Studio 2010:

```
#define STRINGIZE_HELPER(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_HELPER(x)
#define __MESSAGE(text) __pragma( message(__FILE__ "(" STRINGIZE(__LINE__) ")" text) ) 
#define WARNING(text) __MESSAGE( " : Warning: " #text )
#define ERROR(text) __MESSAGE( " : Error: " #text )
#define MESSAGE(text) __MESSAGE( ": " #text )
#define TODO(text) WARNING( TODO: text )
```

and you can use it as:

```
WARNING( This will be a compiler warning );
ERROR( This will be a compiler error );
MESSAGE( Well this is what I have to say about this code );
TODO( Still have to fix 3D rendering );
```

Note that TODO() will also generate a compiler warning; if you don't want to register your TODOs as warnings just use this instead:

```
#define TODO(text) MESSAGE( TODO: text )
```

If you want to display function name inside warnings/errors/TODOs, use this instead:

```
#define WARNING(text) __MESSAGE( " : Warning: (" __FUNCTION__ "): " #text )
#define ERROR(text) __MESSAGE( " : Error: (" __FUNCTION__ "): " #text )
#define MESSAGE(text) __MESSAGE( ": (" __FUNCTION__ "): " #text )
#define TODO(text) __MESSAGE( " : Warning: TODO: (" __FUNCTION__ ") " #text )
```

Comment: I played a bit with those examples. If you write "error :" in the pragma message then you will get a compilation error. Otherwise - it will simply treat it as an output message and compile without an error. As for warning - I'm not sure what's going on there... Any ideas?

Comment: doesn't seem to work with nmake though... I mean, it prints fine, but ERROR(text) doesn't halt the build, and it keeps going.

Answer (score 5):

This suggestion is a bit late I know, but...

You can achieve what you want with the following trick:

```
// stringised version of line number (must be done in two steps)
#define STRINGISE(N) #N
#define EXPAND_THEN_STRINGISE(N) STRINGISE(N)
#define __LINE_STR__ EXPAND_THEN_STRINGISE(__LINE__)

// MSVC-suitable routines for formatting <#pragma message>
#define __LOC__ __FILE__ "(" __LINE_STR__ ")"
#define __OUTPUT_FORMAT__(type) __LOC__ " : " type " : "

// specific message types for <#pragma message>
#define __WARN__ __OUTPUT_FORMAT__("warning")
#define __ERR__ __OUTPUT_FORMAT__("error")
#define __MSG__ __OUTPUT_FORMAT__("programmer's message")
#define __TODO__ __OUTPUT_FORMAT__("to do")
```

Then to generate a message, do e.g.:

```
#pragma message ( __MSG__ "my message" )
```

(From http://rhubbarb.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/user-compilation-messages-c-or-c/)

Answer (score 2):

didn't find anything about warning message but MSVC has creates compile errors just like xcode '#error message` according to [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The way it works for me:

```
#define _message_ "Warning Msg: "
#pragma message(_message_"Need to do something")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `#pragma warning ...`

[Mandatory read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 complains "warning: C4081: expected '('; found 'string'".  Are you sure this works?

Answer (score -1):

MSVC uses

```
#pragma error( "message" )
```

and

```
#pragma warning( "message" )
```

directives, whereas GCC leaves out the `pragma`s.

Comment: MSVC does not know `#pragma error`; do you mean `#error`? `#pragma warning` is for specifying warning behaviour, not generating warnings.

Comment: #pragma warning( "message" ) generates "#pragma warning : unknown user warning type" on Visual Studio 2010.  This seems to indicate that this won't work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score -3):

why don't you use

```
#warning WarningMessage
```

or may be

```
#error ErrorMessage
```

Comment: I know it's not fair, given that the question was clarified _after_ you answered, but obviously the entire premise of the question that these are not supported in Visual Studio, so he's looking for the equivalent (which is the `#pragma warning` syntax).